# Polybuild PHP file

Tags: php, polymer

I am using Polymer 1.0, which I really like, but I can't seem make the `polybuild` tool work with any server side scripting. For example, with a simple example test.php file

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="description" content="PHP Test">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>PHP Test</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:regular,bold,italic,thin,light,bolditalic,black,medium&amp;lang=en">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.5/material.blue-green.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/my-css.css">


    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Polymer -->
    <script src="components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js" async></script>
    <link rel="import" href="components/paper-styles/paper-styles.html">
    <link rel="import" href="components/neon-animation/neon-animated-pages.html" async>
    <link rel="import" href="components/neon-animation/neon-animations.html" async>
  </head>
  <body class="mdl-demo mdl-color--grey-100 mdl-color-text--grey-700 mdl-base fullbleed">

    <?php
    echo 'this is PHP';
    ?>

    <!-- JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.5/material.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/my-javascript.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This file just shows the echoed php text as expected. I use the command

```
polybuild --maximum-crush test.php
```

and I get two files `test.build.html` and `test.build.js` but it just strips out the php. I would like the php left in, but I'm not sure it's possible with the polybuild tool.

Comment: You are correct. It is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Given the source file, `test.php`, and the output file from `polybuild`, `test.build.html`, you can use the [tokenizer extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tokenizer.php) to analyze `test.php`, then infer where to place the php snippets into `test.build.html`.

---

### A rough example

Practically speaking, this would be hard if not nearly impossible for complex imports to vulcan, or complex nesting of php and html in test.php, but for your example scenario it will suffice. If you give me a sample `test.build.html`, I'll make sure my code works perfectly for you. I've had to test on a contrived version.

Here's how it works. Run `polybuild --maximum-crush test.php` as you already are, then run `php polybuild.php test.php test.build.html > test.build.modified.html`. If you take a look at `test.build.modified.html`, you'll see it's `test.build.html` with the php from `test.php` magically where it should be!

Here's the source for `polybuild.php`.

```php
<?php
$buildSource = $argv[1];
$buildHtml   = $argv[2];

$polyPhp = new PolyPhp($buildSource, $buildHtml);
echo $polyPhp->run();

class PolyPhp
{
    private
        $buildSource,
        $buildHtml,
        $sourceAsLines,
        $buildAsLines;

    public function __construct($buildSource, $buildHtml)
    {
        $this->buildSource = $buildSource;
        $this->buildHtml   = $buildHtml;

        // Load the source file as an array of lines
        $this->sourceAsLines = file($buildSource);

        // Load the build file as an array of lines
        $this->buildAsLines = file($buildHtml);
    }

    public function run()
    {
        // Get the tokens from the source php script
        $tokens = token_get_all(file_get_contents($this->buildSource));

        $matchStart = 0;
        $priorHtml  = '';
        foreach($tokens as $token) {
            if(!is_array($token)) {
                continue;
            }

            // Record HTML snippets
            if(token_name($token[0]) == 'T_INLINE_HTML') {
                $priorHtml = $token[1];
            }

            // When we find a php open tag, record the line it occurs on
            if(token_name($token[0]) == 'T_OPEN_TAG') {
                $matchStart = $token[2];
                continue;
            }

            // When we find a closing php tag, reassemble the php block
            // from the buildSource file, then determine where to inject it
            // in the buildHtml file and inject it.
            if(token_name($token[0]) == 'T_CLOSE_TAG') {
                $injectionPoint = $this->findInjectionPoint($priorHtml);
                $php            = $this->extractPhp($matchStart - 1, $token[2]);

                $this->injectPhp($injectionPoint, $php);
            }
        }

        return implode('', $this->buildAsLines);
    }

    /**
     * Inject PHP from the buildSource file
     * into the buildHtml file.
     */
    private function injectPhp($injectPoint, $php)
    {
        $this->buildAsLines = array_merge(
            array_slice($this->buildAsLines, 0, $injectPoint),
            $php,
            array_slice($this->buildAsLines, $injectPoint + 1));
    }

    /**
     * Extract PHP from the buildSource file.
     */
    private function extractPhp($startLine, $finishLine)
    {
        return array_slice($this->sourceAsLines, $startLine, $finishLine - $startLine);
    }

    /**
     * Determine where the injection point in buildHtml is.
     */
    private function findInjectionPoint($priorHtml)
    {
        $lines   = explode("\n", trim($priorHtml));
        $lastTag = trim(array_pop($lines));

        foreach($this->buildAsLines as $line => $tag) {
            $tag = trim($tag);
            if($lastTag == $tag) {
                return $line + 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like you put a lot of work into this, but all it does is put the `<?php echo 'this is PHP'; ?>` between two copies of test.build.html, which is not really useful.

Comment: Maybe I'm still not understanding something. I thought you wanted the php tags from your initial `test.php` placed accordingly in the generated `test.build.html` file.

Comment: Right, the php tag should come right after the `<body>` tag (in my example test.php). In test.build.modified.html is coming after the `</html>` tag and then a whole nother copy of test.build.html is inserted after it.

Comment: For me it is inserted after the `<body>` tag in my test file. If you can provide your `test.build.html` file that I asked for I can make sure it does the same for you. The reason it's currently writing to a separate file is for demonstration purposes, you can easily change it to overwrite the original `test.build.html` file if you wish.

Comment: The example is arbitrary though.

Comment: Either way, I have provided _a solution_ for your question, using the php tokenize extension. I provided a sample solution for a sample input file. YMMV, but you can likely build on it to suit your needs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100167/discussion-between-wogsland-and-quickshiftin).